# Query with multiple left join taking so much time to run

Tags: sql, query-optimization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake I have a table Table_A which is getting its data based on various left join conditions from 4 other tables (Table_1, Table_2, Table_3, Table_4). Each source table has around 20 million of rows and it is expected that after running the query at least 10 million of rows will be inserted in Table_A.

I am using the below condition with multiple Left Joins and OR .

```
Insert into Table_A (x,y,z)
select "column names"
    FROM "Table_1" T1
    LEFT JOIN "Table_2" T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    LEFT JOIN "Table_3" T3 ON  T1.ID = T3.ID or T2.ID = T3.ID
    LEFT JOIN "Table_4" T4 ON T1.ID = T4.ID or T2.ID = T4.ID or T3.ID = T4.ID
```

The query with above condition taking so much time. I tried to use limit by 5 and it took 5 mins to insert just 5 rows (with warehouse size Large). I left it run without limit and had to abort after 12 hours because it was still running. Is there any way we can optimize this query/logic condition to decrease its run time? TIA

Comment: Your query does not have a filtering conditon, so it's reading all the rows of `Table_1` and their related data. A massive query like this one **will take time**. If you want a query to be fast, then you should probably access a limited range of data only.

Comment: @TheImpaler but the table_A has to store all the columns from source tables

Comment: When you go to the History tab in the Snowflake web UI and check the profile for the query, where is it spending most of its time? Look for anything unexpected like a row explosion. Check the number of rows coming out of each step (abbreviated k, M, G for thousand, million, billion rows) to look for anything unexpected.

Comment: You select from `Table_1` and then do `left join` on the same column. What is the purpose of `or`? If `T1.ID = T3.ID` is false then `T2.ID = T3.ID` is obviously false, because this query cannot produce rows, where `T2.id` is not equal to `T1.id`. The same for other conditions

Comment: If you need to join all the tables by `id`, then consider `join ... using(id)`

Answer (score 1):

`OR` kills the optimization of `JOIN`s.  You could use `USING` to avoid this problem with outer joins.  However, that is not necessary (and can be tricky if the join columns do not have the same name).

The chain of joins are `LEFT JOIN`s, so you have all the data in the first table.  So, just use the id from that table for all the joins:

```
Insert into Table_A (x,y,z)
    SELECT "column names"
        FROM "Table_1" T1 LEFT JOIN
             "Table_2" T2 
             ON T1.ID = T2.ID LEFT JOIN
             "Table_3" T3
             ON  T1.ID = T3.ID LEFT JOIN
             "Table_4" T4
             ON T1.ID = T4.ID;
```